# How can I force to work ajax form, method POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, http-status-code-405

Could you, please, help me with one task. I need to make a ajax request for several forms. But I have always gotten an error 405

> jquery.min.js:4 POST http://127.0.0.1:5500/formx.php 405 (Method Not
> Allowed)

```
 <form method="post" class="x_order_form validate">                     
   <input value="" name="client" placeholder="Your name" required="" type="text" class="-metrika-nokeys">
   <input value="" name="tel" id="phone" placeholder="Your phone number" required="" type="text" class="-metrika-nokeys">
   <input value="" name="address" placeholder="Your address" required="" type="text" class="-metrika-nokeys">
   <button>ORDER NOW</button>                      
</form>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'formx.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "html",
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function(response) {
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["client"]) && isset($_POST["tel"]) && isset($_POST["address"])) { 

    $result = array(
        'client' => $_POST["client"],
        'tel' => $_POST["tel"],
        'address' => $_POST["address"]
    ); 

    echo json_encode($result); 
}
```

Comment: Is your webserver really running on port 5500? What webserver are you using? Normally a 405 means the webserver isn't configured to allow that specific HTTP method (POST, in this case) to be used (possibly just for the given URL, or possibly as a wider setting).

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Could you please tell me how I can check if my webserver is running on port 5500. I have never worked with back before. And don’t clear understand what and how I should do.

Comment: It would be in the webserver's settings. Can't tell you any more because you didn't mention which webserver product you're using. But you should be able to read its manual and/or search Google to find out how to check the configuration.

Comment: I got it. May I ask the last question. Is this an error related to the configuration or due to the fact that I try to open it in browser from Visual studio I don’t use any domain or local Webserver. I have known only how to work with html and JS.

Comment: If you're not using a webserver then yes that's maybe the problem - there's nowhere to send the request. Do you mean Visual Studio Code? (the traditional Visual Studio does not support PHP at all.) Have you installed any kind of plugin into Visual Studio Code to run a PHP webserver?